# Returning an array of actions defined in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller, and in my tests I want to do this:

```
%i(index show new create edit update destroy publish suspend).each do |action|
  # code
end
```

But it's verbose, and I need to do it in a number of tests. I know I can do the following:

```
ProjectsController.instance_methods.take(8).each do |action|
  # code
end
```

But it's brittle, especially if we remove the :suspend action. Is there a rails way of getting all the methods defined in a controller file, and no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
ProjectsController.action_methods
```

in your test. Any public method will be returned. Keep in mind do define any non action methods as private

If you want to do this for multiple controllers, you can have a look at [shared example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

eg.

```
shared_examples "test actions" do
  controller_class.action_methods.each do |action|
    <your tests>
  end
end
```

and in your test file, simple say

```
it_behaves_like "test actions"
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, and the tip on shared_examples :)